# How to identify and merge connected cases in a list of integer vectors

Tags: r, list, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have a list with elements which contain either single integers or integer vectors.

```
int_list <- list(
    c(1, 15),
    c(3, 19),
    c(2, 16),
    c(4, 19),
    c(5, 21),
    c(19, 28),
    c(28, 30),
    17
)
```

As you can see the second and fourth element contain the integer 19. I want to merge such cases into one vector. Therefore the expected/desired result in that case would be:

```
int_list_merged <- list(
    c(1, 15),
    c(3, 4, 19, 28, 30),
    c(2, 16),
    c(5, 21),
    17
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition that `list(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(3,4))` returns `list(c(1,2,3,4))` means we have to pass over the list until it stops changing.

We can use a recursive function which stops calling itself when that condition is satisfied.

```r
create_merged_list <- function(l, check_finished_list = NULL) {
    new_l <- unique(lapply(seq(l), \(i) merge_elements(l, i)))

    if (identical(check_finished_list, new_l)) {
        return(new_l)
    }
    create_merged_list(new_l, l)
}
```

The workhorse function this calls is `merge_elements()`, which iterates over each element of the list, merging it with other elements with which it shares values, and returns a new list.

```r
merge_elements <- function(l, i) {
    l_compare <- l[-i]
    el <- l[[i]]
    match_vals <- which(outer(el, unlist(l_compare), \(x, y) x == y), arr.ind = TRUE)[, "col"]

    if (!length(match_vals)) {
        return(el)
    }

    l_breaks <- cumsum(lengths(l_compare))

    l_match_idx <- vapply(match_vals, \(x) min(which(x <= l_breaks)), integer(1))
    new_el <- sort(unique(c(el, unlist(l_compare[l_match_idx]))))
    new_el
}
```

##### Output

```r
create_merged_list(int_list) 
# [[1]]
# [1]  1 15

# [[2]]
# [1]  3  4 19 28 30

# [[3]]
# [1]  2 16

# [[4]]
# [1]  5 21

# [[5]]
# [1] 17

identical(create_merged_list(int_list), int_list_merged) 
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

An approach using `expand.grid` to construct combinations.
Then using 2 `mapply`s, one to get the merged data and another one to get the non-matching indices.

```
Merge <- function(List){
  Seq <- seq_along(List)
  ExpSeq <- expand.grid(Seq, Seq)
  rows <- which(upper.tri(matrix(Seq, ncol=max(Seq), nrow=max(Seq))))

  c(list(as.vector(na.omit(unique(unlist(
    mapply(\(x, y) 
      ifelse(any(List[[x]] %in% List[[y]]), list(c(List[[x]], List[[y]])), NA), 
        ExpSeq[rows,1], ExpSeq[rows,2])))))),

    List[Seq[!Seq %in% na.omit(unique(unlist(
    mapply(\(x, y) 
      ifelse(any(List[[x]] %in% List[[y]]), list(c(x, y)), NA), 
        ExpSeq[rows,1], ExpSeq[rows,2]))))]]
  )
}
```

output

```
[[1]]
[1]  3 19  4 28 30

[[2]]
[1]  1 15

[[3]]
[1]  2 16

[[4]]
[1]  5 21

[[5]]
[1] 17
```

Answer (score 1):

## base R option

You can define a function that keeps updating the clustering labels (if elements in `int_list` can be merged) until nothing can be merged any further. You can do it with two `for` loops, e.g.,

```
f <- function(l) {
    repeat {
        grp <- seq_along(l)
        for (i in 1:(length(l) - 1)) {
            for (j in (i + 1):length(l)) {
                if (any(l[[i]] %in% l[[j]])) {
                    # update the labelling of groups
                    grp[j] <- grp[i]
                }
            }
        }
        # update the list as per the updated group labels
        lst <- tapply(l, grp, \(x) unique(unlist(x)))
        if (length(lst) < length(l)) {
            l <- lst
        } else {
            return(unname(lst))
        }
    }
}
```

and you will see

```
> f(int_list)
[[1]]
[1]  1 15

[[2]]
[1]  3 19  4 28 30

[[3]]
[1]  2 16

[[4]]
[1]  5 21

[[5]]
[1] 17
```

---

## `igraph` option

If you would like to solve it with `igraph`, it actually can be interpreted as disconnected components of graph.

Two `igraph` options are given as below for example:

```
library(igraph)

int_list %>%
    setNames(paste0("x", seq_along(.))) %>%
    stack() %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    set_vertex_attr(name = "type", value = startsWith(names(V(.)), "x")) %>%
    bipartite.projection() %>%
    pluck("proj1") %>%
    decompose() %>%
    lapply(\(x) as.integer(names(V(x))))
```

or

```
library(igraph)

int_list %>%
    setNames(paste0("x", seq_along(.))) %>%
    stack() %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    components() %>%
    membership() %>%
    subset(!startsWith(names(.), "x")) %>%
    {
        unname(split(as.integer(names(.)), .))
    }
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1]  1 15

[[2]]
[1]  3 19  4 28 30

[[3]]
[1]  2 16

[[4]]
[1]  5 21

[[5]]
[1] 17
```